# CryptImportKey return "Bad Version of provider." error

Tags: c++, rsa, cryptoapi

i crate a certificate and private key file by makecert.exe
with below command

makecert.exe -n "CN=test" -pe -ss my -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -m 96 -a sha1 -len 2048 -r test.cer -sv test.pvk

and i have a test.pvk file

now i want use private key in my program

CryptImportKey function return "Bad Version of provider." error

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "tchar.h"

#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <cryptuiapi.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "cryptui.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    HANDLE hPrivateKeyFile; 

    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey;

    BYTE* pbPublicKey ;
    BYTE* pbPrivateKey;

    DWORD dwPublicKeyLen ;
    DWORD dwPrivateKeyLen;

    WCHAR* strFileName=L"test.pvk";

    // Open private key file    
    if ((hPrivateKeyFile = CreateFile(strFileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {         
          printf(("CreateFile error 0x%x\n")); exit(0);       
    }

    // Get file size    
    if ((dwPrivateKeyLen = GetFileSize(hPrivateKeyFile, NULL)) == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {   
          printf(("GetFileSize error 0x%x\n")); exit(0);               
    }

    // Create a buffer for the private key  
    if (!(pbPrivateKey = (BYTE *)malloc(dwPrivateKeyLen)))
    {         
          printf(("malloc error 0x%x\n"));  exit(0);          
    }

    // Read private key 
    if (!ReadFile(hPrivateKeyFile, pbPrivateKey, dwPrivateKeyLen, &dwPrivateKeyLen, NULL))
    {         
          printf(("ReadFile error 0x%x\n")); exit(0);          
    }

    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) 
    {          
          printf(("CryptAcquireContext error 0x%x\n")); exit(0);      
    }

    // Import private key   
    if (!CryptImportKey(hCryptProv, pbPrivateKey, dwPrivateKeyLen, 0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey))
    {         
          printf(("CryptImportKey error 0x%x\n"));  
          DWORD lastError=GetLastError();//Bad Version of provider.
          exit(0);              
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait you're trying to import a *private* key file without the associated decryption key (remember, your private key is encrypted).

Comment: i didnt enter password on create private key

Answer (score 0):

- In CryptAcquireContext, change the last parameter to CRYPT_NEWKEYSET|CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT
- Check the return value of hCryptProv.  It should be non-szero.  CryptAcquireContext can return TRUE and at the same time set hCryptProv to zero.

Comment: i change parameter to CRYPT_NEWKEYSET|CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT and hCryptProv is non-zero but i have error still

Comment: Instead of using the default provider, try using one of the providers in wincrypt.h (around line 512).  You have quite a few to choose from.

Comment: You need to decode the key first using CryptDecodeObjectEx and then import the decoded item.  Have a look at http://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/capi_pem.cpp